# Height of cell in vaadin table variable

Tags: vaadin

I have a Table in Vaadin. One column is a String type so its size is variable. Hence, I'd like to make the width of the column fix (with expand ratio) but the height of every row should be variable (according to its content - the String).

i.e., this is what is intended

```
Date      | Item | Motive
01-02-2013|banana|Sold out
02-02-2013|DVD   |An alternative purchase
          |      |has occurred
02-02-2013|Mixer |Sold out
```

However, with the String `An alternative purchase has occurred` results in

```
Date      | Item | Motive
01-02-2013|banana|Sold out
02-02-2013|DVD   |An alternative purchase
02-02-2013|Mixer |Sold out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Vaadin Table doesn't support word-wrap in table cells.

This `CSS` trick (once published on vaadin forums) worked for me:

```css
.wordwrap-table .v-table-cell-wrapper {
   /* Do not specify any margins, paddings or borders here */
   white-space: normal;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

You have to set style name to table:

```java
fooTable.setStyleName("wordwrap-table");
```

[Chapter 8 (Themes)](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) in book of vaadin has a good introduction on customizing css and creating custom themes.